# Gnucash - view statements

Tags: gnucash, bank-statements

In Gnucash, I've been starting to use statement reconciliation for my bank & credit card accounts.  Is there some way to see the statements I've already reconciled?  Ideally I'd be able to see all the transactions that are assigned to it, but even just a list of the dates and beginning/ending balances would be helpful for figuring out what statements I still need to address.

**UPDATE** - I'm getting the idea from the two answers so far that the statements themselves (info on the closing date, starting & ending balance for each statement) aren't stored anywhere, and the only information is either per-account (date of last reconcile) or per-transaction (reconciled status).  Is that so?

Answer (score 4):

An added tip in [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/105950/17718) should help you achieve what you need:

> On your accounts page, there is a little drop down on the right side
>   that allows you to display more columns. One of them is "Last
>   Reconcile Date", and then you can see directly on your account page
>   which accounts need to be reconciled. This way you can glance at your
>   accounts and know your numbers are "accurate as of [some-date]". If
>   you have a lot of accounts that need to be reconciled each month this
>   helps quickly show you which ones haven't been done yet.

You can also add a column to display the reconciled balance, and you can sort by the last reconciled date column to show which accounts you should focus on in your current session.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't really address the need.  I'd really like to see which individual statements (reconciliation sessions) have happened, not just the date of the latest one.

Comment: @KenWilliams the concept of reconciliation implies everything up to that date has already been reconciled, so only the single latest date would be needed. Normally you would reconcile statements in time ascending order. Is that not what you're doing? Or maybe you are but you still want to see previous reconciliation dates for some reason?

Comment: Unfortunately this restriction (needing to reconcile in time-ascending order) can be quite inconvenient - for example if I import all my transactions for the past 2 years, then want to go back and import previous years.  I've needed to do this several times, for various reasons, so I feel like I can't be the only one?

Comment: @KenWilliams - I agree it's hard if you're that far behind. The (let's hope) one-time catch up work can indeed be daunting. In order to do it out of order, you will need a temporary place holder adjustment. For example, suppose the sum of all transactions (credits and debits) from 2015-2018 = $1234.56. In order to reconcile after that you could add an adjustment with that credit on 2018-12-31 and use account Imbalance. An example description might be "All transactions for 2015-01-01 through 2018-12-31". As you reconcile backwards, change the amount, date, and memo for that entry.

Comment: @KenWilliams and if you then reconcile in gaps within the larger gap, you would need to keep adding temporary adjustment transactions any place they are needed to keep reconciles after that date in balance. So essentially you would have to manually do what you want with temporary adjustments until you fill in all the gaps. By the way, needing to do this isn't really a restriction in GnuCash per se, I suspect all accounting software would require this. There's no way to start from a specific date and virtual amount without the transactions up to that date adding up to that number...

Comment: About that last point - actually Banktivity had a very good way of tackling this, because *the transactions aren't just marked "reconciled", they're associated with a specific statement*.  So picking some statement at random to reconcile in the middle of a slew of unreconciled transactions is actually a great way of going about it.  And you can work backwards from newest (usually most important) to oldest (usually least important).

Comment: To be clear, there were many other reasons why I finally gave up on Banktivity, to avoid gouging my eyes out. =)

Comment: @KenWilliams OK. I didn't realize you already had the transactions imported, but not reconciled yet, and you are working backwards. In that case it's possible you don't need the adjustment entries, if the imported transactions are all correct. Although this doesn't give you what you want, one thing that might help a bit is, when viewing your account, do a search and choose "Reconcile" as the search criteria, and then whichever option(s) make sense. As long as you leave Reconciled unchecked you'll see all the transactions that aren't done yet (and you'd know which statements they're from).

Answer (score 3):

the way to do it is to create a **transaction report** for the dates you are interested in and set filter status to Unreconciled (see below).

You can adjust report in very handy ways, for example sorting according to dates (see sorting tab - same picture), rather than account names - if you are looking at expense accounts for example. I would typically want to display: `Date | Description | Memo | Account Name | Other Account Name` and `Enable links` - so if you find a transaction you want to look onto you just double click that link and it takes you straight into the account register. It is handy to open the report in `New Window with Page` on Windows menu. Then you switch between two windows - one is the report, the other is the actual account (i.e. main window). It works well also for finding duplicate transactions - they usually are within days of each other. Just set your time period of interest and choose to `sort by amount` - then run your eyes over the list - you will spot duplicates very quickly.

Under `General Tab` give the report a name. Save this by clicking OK. Then - before you close your report - use `Reports - Save Report Configuration` - you will have to give the name to the report in that `Saved Report Configurations` list again. So next time you can open the report quickly and just adjust the parameters you want to change (e.g. sorting). When you have made some changes, for example removed the duplicate transaction you found - click refresh button above the report.

If I want to print the reports I find that adjusting report stylesheets (under `Edit` menu) is very useful - I typically decrease font sizes by 2 to 3 points to make lines fit neatly on A4 layout.

[image: Report Filter Tab]